# python sqlite3 select, no results when converting numpy array to list

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, sqlite

I am trying to perform a `SELECT` query on a sqlite database with python 3 and sqlite3. 
When I use a list of values in the `WHERE .. IN (list of values)` statement it works but if I use a numpy array converted to a list it returns nothing.

Here is a minimal working example :

```
import numpy as np
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('test.sqlite')

c = conn.cursor()

# create test table
c.execute("CREATE TABLE test (col1 INTEGER)")

values = [(v,) for v in range(10000)]

c.executemany("INSERT INTO test (col1) VALUES (?)", values)

conn.commit()
```

Executing a SELECT query using a list:

```
c.execute("SELECT col1 FROM test WHERE col1 IN (?,?,?)", [0,17,42])
c.fetchall()
```

returns : `[(0,), (17,), (42,)]` -> ok

But,

```
c.execute("SELECT col1 FROM test WHERE col1 IN (?,?,?)", list(np.array([0,17,42])))
c.fetchall()
```

returns `[]`

Although,

```
list(np.array([0,17,42])) == [0,17,42]
```

returns True

Is it expected?

Comment: Try `np.array(...).tolist()`.   `list(array...)` performs an incomplete translation.

Comment: Thanks, it is working with `.tolist()`!
@hpaulj Can you elaborate on why `list(array)` performs an incomplete translation? How can I test whether a list has been incompletely translated?